# How to check if a shared table exists using DolphinDB Python API?

Tags: python, dolphindb, shared-objects

Does anyone know how to check if a shared table exists using the DolphinDB Python API? For example, if I intend to check if there is a table named “A20160405“ in the Shared Tables in GUI, can I execute `existsTable("shared", "A20160405")`?

Comment: Have a look in the documentation of [DolphineDB](https://dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/l/listTables.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no native/direct interface designed to do this. You can use the built-in function `objs`. Refer to the following method: `s.run("select * from objs(true) where shared=true")`.